# The project references NuGet packages that are not on this computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, nuget

i'm getting following error when i build my solution in visual studio 2015.
[image]

but when i try to add that particular package then visual studio show it already added

[image]

Comment: When you right-click on the solution and select "Restore NuGet packages", does that help?

Comment: nope it didn't help, i tried it several times. Cleaned the solution rebuild it but the same problem i'm having

Comment: Delete the packages folder and retry restore packages. (Make sure to keep a backup of solution)

Comment: The version you are installing 1.0.7 is different to the version 1.0.5 in the error message. I would open your .csproj file into a text editor and see if there is a reference to the 1.0.5 version which is not being used by the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you notice something? the version is different you need version 1.0.5 instead of 1.0.7

Answer (score 0):

Open Nuget Package Manager and pick "Unistall" on this package, than istall it again. If this does not help you do next:

1. Unload project and remove all reference on this package from `.csproj` file
2. Remove reference on this package from `Web.config` (or `App.config`) if it there.
3. Remove reference from `packages.config` file
4. Install via nuget you package again.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Right click solution in visual studio and select "Restore Nuget Packages", it will download the missing packages

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command in the Package Manage Console:

```
Update-Package -reinstall -Project YourProjectName
```

It is by project, but this way is garanteed it works, at least in 100% of  cases that happen to me.